# Removing unused spaces and commas from a string in Java

Tags: java, string, jsp

I have a question, and I'm sure there is a relatively simple answer to this, but at the moment I'm having a massive brain fart and can't seem to think of an elegant solution that doesn't involve a ridiculous myriad of if statements.

Basically, I have a web page that is dynamically updating the users present into a string, stylised as such

> User1, User2, User3, User4

However, when I delete one of these users, from a different location, they are removed from the list, but I'm left with the following

*Beginning*

> , User2, User3, User4

*Middle*

> User1, , User3, User4

*End*

> User1, User2, User3,

If anyone knows of a relatively easy way to remove these unwanted commas, that would be really helpful; it's been bugging me for hours.

Comment: This question isn't clear enough. Where are these strings? do you do this in server or in jsp? this can probably be done with replace(), or better a replaceFirst(), but without some more details i can't help you out

Comment: I presume from your description that when a user is deleted you are modifying the output string, rather than just regenerating it. Is that right?

Comment: The strings are in jsp, and are regenerated every time a page loads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could match `,$`, `^,` and `, ,` with a regex and replace it with empty

Comment: I suppose you wanted to write `^,` and `,$`

Comment: Clearly, OP is not the only one with a brainfart ;) fixed. And thanks!

Comment: Are we talking about a regex like this

display.replaceAll(",$|^,|, ,", "");

Sorry, its been awhile since i've written anything like this, so i'm quite rusty

Answer (score 1):

You could simply try:

```
String s = "User1, , User2, User3, ,...;
s = s.replaceAll(", ,", ",");
```

Comment: I'd probably take into account there could be extra spaces.  Because you _know_ it's eventually going to happen.

Comment: You'd need a couple of other statements for final and initial commas

Answer (score 1):

I would do a split and then a join.

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
final Iterable<String> fields = Splitter.on(",")
  .trimResults()
  .omitEmptyStrings()
  .split(data);

final String trimmedData = Joiner.on(",").join(fields);
```

With this you can even validate the input fields with [`Iterables.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
",User1, , User3, User4,".replaceAll("[\\s],|,$|^,", "");
```

->

```
User1, User3, User4
```